# How to Get Consumer Price Index Data from Bureau of Labor Statistics with Cheerio/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, cheerio

I used to import table data from [US Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/cpi.t02.htm) with this code below.  But it doesn't work anymore. Obviously the website must be changed, but I couldn't figure the root cause, although I still see all the table data under tbody tag.

I got empty data with this code.  What needs to be changed in the code?  Thank you for any help!

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://www.bls.gov/news.release/cpi.t02.htm';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  var $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  var data = $('tbody').find('td').toArray().map(el => $(el).text().trim());
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `UrlFetchApp` is or where it comes from, but running this with plain old `fetch, as in `fetch(url).then(res => res.text())`, I get 2030 data points, starting with `[ '100.000', '3.0',  '0.3',  '0.4',  '0.1',  '0.2',`. Do you have any error handling in that `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?

Comment: UrlFetchApp is a method in Google Apps Script (within Google Sheet) that I'm using in a lot of my applications on daily basis.   It doesn't have any error, simply no data under <tbody> tag.  I guess something is related to the tag name in the website structure.

Comment: Confirming this works on Node and `fetch` for me. Whatever `UrlFetchApp` is, `{ muteHttpExceptions: true }` sounds dangerous. You might have a suppressed HTTP exception that tells you what the issue is. It's odd that it's _synchronous_ (but I don't know anything about GAS).